# Script error: no module named common.hyperparameters

Tags: python, nlp

I am trying to run this code below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

if __name__ == "__main__":
**import common.hyperparameters, common.options**
HYPERPARAMETERS = common.hyperparameters.read("language-model")
HYPERPARAMETERS, options, args, newkeystr = common.options.reparse(HYPERPARAMETERS)
import hyperparameters

import vocabulary
import common.idmap

words = []

import string
for i, l in enumerate(common.file.myopen(HYPERPARAMETERS["MONOLINGUAL_VOCABULARY"])):
    if HYPERPARAMETERS["INCLUDE_UNKNOWN_WORD"] and i+1 >= HYPERPARAMETERS["MONOLINGUAL_VOCABULARY_SIZE"]:
        break
    if not HYPERPARAMETERS["INCLUDE_UNKNOWN_WORD"] and i >= HYPERPARAMETERS["MONOLINGUAL_VOCABULARY_SIZE"]:
        break
    (cnt, w) = string.split(l)
    words.append(w)

v = common.idmap.IDmap(words, allow_unknown=HYPERPARAMETERS["INCLUDE_UNKNOWN_WORD"])
assert v.len == HYPERPARAMETERS["MONOLINGUAL_VOCABULARY_SIZE"]
vocabulary.write(v)
```

Here I have a common folder that contains the hyperparameters.py, even then it is not able to merge that script into my main program. I don't know how to add this to my program.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to import .py file from another directory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory)

Comment: that is not working :(