# How to import a function from a module in the same folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to separate my script into several files with functions, so I moved some functions into separate files and want to import them into one main file. The structure is:

```
core/
  main.py
  posts_run.py
```

`posts_run.py` has two functions, `get_all_posts` and `retrieve_posts`, so I try import `get_all_posts` with:

```
from posts_run import get_all_posts
```

Python 3.5 gives the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_posts'
```

Main.py contains following rows of code:

```
import vk
from configs import client_id, login, password
session = vk.AuthSession(scope='wall,friends,photos,status,groups,offline,messages',   app_id=client_id, user_login=login,
                     user_password=password)
api = vk.API(session)
```

Then i need to import api to functions, so I have ability to get API calls to vk.

Full stack trace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/gited/vkscrap/core/main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from posts_run import get_all_posts
  File "E:\gited\vkscrap\core\posts_run.py", line 7, in <module>
    from main import api, absolute_url, fullname
  File "E:\gited\vkscrap\core\main.py", line 26, in <module>
    from posts_run import get_all_posts
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_posts'
```

api - is a `api = vk.API(session)` in main.py.
absolute_url and fullname are also stored in main.py.
I am using PyCharm 2016.1 on Windows 7, Python 3.5 x64 in virtualenv.
How can I import this function?

Comment: Check out the import docs here, should tell you everything you need to know: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: @DanielleM.I've read several questions on stack, and read docs for importing, but it has no effect.

Comment: A module is not a module without an __init__.py. Perhaps that is missing?

Comment: @Ben: That's a \_\_init__.py file.

Comment: What file has the `from posts_run import get_all_posts` statement in it? Is that the file PyCharm is executing?

Comment: Can we see the full stacktrace? It seems tome you have a circular import, do you import anything from `main.py` in to `posts_run.py`?

Comment: Show us the whole stack trace. It sounds like you have a circular import you're not showing us.

Comment: @user2357112, you are right, there is one problem with imports.

Comment: @user2357112, should I split functions from main.py if it need api variable from main.py?

Comment: @OleksiyOvdiyenko: Have them take the API object as an argument, and they won't need the variable.

Comment: @user2357112, ok, thank you)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You need to add `__init__.py` in your core folder. You getting this error because python does not recognise your folder as [python package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

After that do

```
from .posts_run import get_all_posts
#    ^ here do relative import
# or
from core.posts_run import get_all_posts
# because your package named 'core' and importing looks in root folder
```

Comment: I did this, it also had no effect. Python raises same error

Comment: @OleksiyOvdiyenko are you sure your python module is in your **local directory**?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry, yes, it is in local dir

Comment: @OleksiyOvdiyenko well  Sardorbek's answer shouldn't be giving you a import error. Is your other file in the same folder as your main file, or is it in another sub-folder?

Comment: @Mr.goosberry in same folder

Comment: @OleksiyOvdiyenko well something else is wrong. Try running the python IDLE. open your main script and try running it from there. The problem may lie with Pycharm.

Comment: when I ```from core.posts_run import get_all_posts``` it raises ```ImportError: No module named 'core'```. For relative import with ```.posts_run''' it raises ```SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import```

Comment: @OleksiyOvdiyenko this means your `core` package is not loaded to your `PYTHONPATH`.  this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16981921/relative-imports-in-python-3

Comment: This answer gets many things wrong. [Since 3.3](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/), `__init__.py` is **not necessary** for this and is **not used** to decide that a folder represents a package. The error **does not** occur "because Python does not recognize the folder as a package"; it occurs because the code attempts **absolute rather than relative** import and because the package root folder **is not on the `sys.path`**.

Answer (score 6):

MyFile.py:

```
def myfunc():
    return 12
```

start python interpreter:

```
>>> from MyFile import myFunc
>>> myFunc()
12
```

Alternatively:

```
>>> import MyFile
>>> MyFile.myFunc()
12
```

Does this not work on your machine?

Comment: He might not have his custom python module in his local directory.

Comment: I'm not sure of the exact rules or order, but python will look in the current directory as well as sys.path, $PYTHONPATH, etc.

Comment: Yes, it works with this func, but when i try to call ```import posts_run``` it raises ```ImportError: cannot import name 'get_all_posts'```

Comment: if you in the core folder, you should be able to reference posts_run directly. If you are in the root folder, try referring to ti as core.posts_run

Comment: @DanielleM. No, I don't believe your correct. I believe that you must add the path to your python module at runtime for python to find where it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory

Comment: @DanielleM.if i try to import core.posts_run it says that ```ImportError: No module named 'core'```, __init__ in core folder

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't find the module to import because it is executed from another directory.

Open a terminal and cd into the script's folder, then execute python from there.

Run this code in your script to print from where python is being executed from:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
```

EDIT:
This is a demonstration of what I mean

Put the code above in a `test.py` file located at `C:\folder\test.py`

open a terminal and type

```
python3 C:\folder\test.py
```

This will output the base directory of python executable

now type

```
cd C:\folder
python3 test.py
```

This will output `C:\folder\`. So if you have other modules in `folder` importing them should not be a problem

I usually write a bash/batch script to cd into the directory and start my programs. This allows to have zero-impact on host machines

Comment: I need to add to path every time i make new project with files in folder?

Answer (score 0):

A cheat solution can be found from this question (question is [Why use sys.path.append(path) instead of sys.path.insert(1, path)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10095037/why-use-sys-path-appendpath-instead-of-sys-path-insert1-path) ). Essentially you do the following

```
    import sys
    sys.path.insert(1, directory_path_your_code_is_in)
    import file_name_without_dot_py_at_end
```

This will get round that as you are running it in PyCharm 2016.1, it might be in a different current directory to what you are expecting...

Comment: This article goes into more detail - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/897792/pythons-sys-path-value/38403654#38403654