# How do I import the url_page function from my nav.py file into mine.py?

Tags: python

These are my files:

```
./mine.py
./nav.py
```

I'm trying to import the `url_page` function from the `nav.py` file into `mine.py`.

**nav.py**

```py
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
    import time
    
    # --- ROTINAS INICIAIS ---
    
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, executable_path="./geckodriver")
    print("Firefox Headless Browser Invoked")
    driver.get("https://www.google.com.br/")
    
    
    def url_page(code_share):
        elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
        code_share = code_share + " código"
        elem.send_keys(code_share + Keys.ENTER);
        time.sleep(2)
        return print(driver.current_url)
```

**mine.py**

```py
    import json
    import time
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    from nav.py import url_page
    
    url_page("AMBEV S.A.")
```

This is the error message:

```
    Firefox Headless Browser Invoked
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "mine.py", line 4, in <module>
    from nav.py import url_page
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named "nav.py"; "nav" is not a package
```

Comment: Try `from .nav import url_page` or `from nav import url_page`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to import a function from a module in the same folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39233077/how-to-import-a-function-from-a-module-in-the-same-folder)

Answer (score -1):

in `mine.py`

add `import nav` and use `nav.url_page()`

remove `from nav.py import url_page` from your code