# How to import a python file?

Tags: python

Hello I look into the forum and find a lot of people who had this problem but the solutions were not successful for me!

I have one main file: "PythonApplication1.py" in the directory : "PythonApplication"
In this directory I have an other directory : "classes"
In "classes" I created 4 python files.

I just want to import **one** file (and next all the directory "classes") but nothing works! 
I try this: (in the main file : PythonApplication1.py)

```
import os
import os.path
import sys
sys.path.append('/classes/classeCarte.py')

print(os.getcwd())
# it gives me : :H/..../PythonApplication1 : its OK

#xxx = os.path.basename(path)
# I tried this : it gives me : "classeCarte.py"
#print(xxx)

carteTEST = Cartes(11, 4)
carteTEST.afficherValeur()
carteTEST.afficherCouleur()
```

At then end I call functions created in the class: "classeCarte.py" and it doesn't work. I have the error:

```
names Cartes is not defined
```

I tried to write at the beginning:

```
from classes import *
```

or just:

```
import /classes/classeCarte.py
```

It never worked ...

Thank you for your help!

ps: I work on VisualStudio and can see the tree may be is it help on this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to import .py file from another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create an python package can be imported you need to create `__init__.py` in the folder.
The `__init__.py` can be a empty file.
In your case you have to create `__init__.py` in your classes folder

Then you may use the following import statement:
`from classes.classeCarte import *`

Comment: ok thank you very much it works ! but just an observation : it's strange it works because in my code I have the line {from classes.classeCarte import *} underlined in green like it was wrong...  the message is : "Unable to resolve 'classe.classeCarte' Intellisense may be missing for this module"

Comment: I am not sure about this. This could the problem if you manually add ```__init__.py``` and the IDE does not interpret this project structure properly.

A proper way is to add a package with your IDE, if your project is a python project it should auto add ```__init__.py``` in the package folder and able to interpret the package structure .