# sys.path.insert cannnot import other python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, python-import, importerror

What the title says. I have the following file structure inside the path`C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python file\5.0.8`:

```
5.0.8\
   tree one\
      little main.py
      sample_tree1.py
   tree two\
       sample_tree2.py
```

the following is what's inside `little main.py`:

```
import sys
import sample_tree1

sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python file\5.0.8\tree two\sample_tree2.py')

import sample_tree2
```

I want to import `sample_tree2.py`, but an error is raised as soon as I run the `little main.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-486a3fafa7f2>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/User/Desktop/all python file/5.0.8/tree one/little main.py', wdir='C:/Users/User/Desktop/all python file/5.0.8/tree one')

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\User\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/User/Desktop/all python file/5.0.8/tree one/little main.py", line 12, in <module>
    import sample_tree2

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sample_tree2'
```

So what happened? I followed [this post's top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory) in order to import a file from another branch of path, but it doesn't work.

Thank you in advance

---

EDIT:

I am looking for a solution that:

1) does not require changing the current working directory

2) does not require changing the names of the files

3) does not require changing the configuration of the python terminal stuff

---

EDIT2:
Added some capscreens of files and folder structures, and error messages

[image: path without sample_tree2.py]
[image: path with sample_tree2.py]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Try with directories without spaces in it.

Comment: @ipaleka this requires changing the names of the directory, which is not allowed. But still, even changing the `tree two` to `treetwo`, and uses `import treetwo.sample_tree2`, the error `No module named 'treetwo'` is raised

Comment: Sorry, figured out that condition too late. Try with creating os.path.join objects instead of strings as that has been your issue here: take a look at the different way your path is presented in stack trace compared to paths from above.

Comment: @ipaleka can you type them down to the answer so that I can run the code without misinterpreting your reply?

Comment: @ipaleka I used `os.path.exists(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python file\5.0.8\treetwo\sample_tree2.py') == True` to check whethere there is a typo in the string of absolute path, turns out I have been correct; the absolute path is right, so the issue does not lie in the string of path

Comment: Did you try removing the file name from the path? Then you are inserting an actual path into the path list.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere what does 'removing the file name from the path' mean? move `sample_tree2.py` to desktop and put it abck under `treetwo` and run `little main.py` again? or `sys.path.insert(0, r'C:\Users\User\Desktop\all python file\5.0.8\tree two'`?

I have done both cases and the result still hasn't changed

Comment: Is it `treetwo` as per your `path.exists` comment or `tree two` as per your more recent comment? I was talking about case 2, just removing the file name from the `insert` command. This works correctly on ubuntu with py3.7. You can also try `print(sys.path)` to see the path list and on mine, I don't see any file names.

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere I tried both versions of with/without filename in the insert commend(in the pictures I uploaded), they both failed for some reasons. I added more pictures as well to showcase my full folder hierarchy and error messages.

Comment: Line 25 on your first pic is trying to import the folder not the file. Also the `os.path.exists` will return true if the path or file exists (not that they are added to the path list you want), so makes sense that both are true, but, you didn't add the path with the `insert`, which you still need to do and can verify with `print(sys.path)`

Comment: @DaveStSomeWhere Do you mind typing your answer to the answer below？I think it is better this way, because then I can copy your code and run it and that there will be 0 difference between your code and my code, which makes debugging a whole lot easier

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sys.path.insert()` command inserts a path into the system path and should not contain the filename.

Please try below using your structure:

little main.py:

```py
import sys
import sample_tree1

sys.path.insert(0, r'/my/absolute/path/5.0.8/treetwo')
print(sys.path)  # view the path and verify your insert

import sample_tree2

print(sample_tree2.tree2_func())
```

sample_tree2.py in treetwo

```py
def tree2_func():
    return 'called tree2'
```

Outputs:

> ['/my/absolute/path/5.0.8/treetwo', '... other paths']
>
> called tree2

Comment: It works. Before this I tried `import treetwo`, `import treetwo.sample_tree2` and `from treetwo import sample_tree2`,  and I somehow managed to miss the most obviosu one. How dumb I really was. Huge thanks for your follow-up

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps using a GUI terminal to recompile would allow all those three things your trying to do. Or even using Flutter only my opinion

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35072005)