# Module import from own directory not found. How to fix it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

A get an error when trying to run my code but somehow vs code doesn't see the path error.

The error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_formats'

The structure of my code is:

```
application
├── data_processor
│   ├── extract_movements.py
│   └── get_formats
│       └── get_formats.py
├── get_user_input
│   ├── get_bank_name.py
│   └── get_pdf_name.py
└── operate.py
```

And the error occures in `extract_movements.py` where I am trying to import a funtion located in `get_formats.py` using:

```
from get_formats.get_formats import get_transaction_tags_format, get_transaction_dates_format
```

The complete error shown is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/application/operate.py", line 6, in <module>
    from data_processor.extract_movements import extract_movements
  File "/Users/username/Desktop/application/data_processor/extract_movements.py", line 1, in <module>
    from get_formats.get_formats import get_transaction_tags_format, get_transaction_dates_format
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'get_formats'
```

I see some answers talk about an `__init__.py` file in the application directory or the data_processor directory so i tried adding that but got no results. Also have no idea what an empty file with the name `__init__.py`

Comment: maybe put a try except block, trying to import it how you are, and except with ```from data_processor.get_formats.get_formats import get_transaction_tags_format, get_transaction_dates_format```
As the originating file is in the main directory, it cannot find the "get_formats" file in the main directory.

Comment: Does that mean that any time I import a function into a new file I call it from the main directory? I feel stupid cause that works and I can't believe I didn't try that  Well didn't use try and except just replaced the code

Comment: Does the __init__.py code have anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you make an __init__.py script in your directory, you'll be able to access sibling files.

Why wasn't your __init__.py working? - You need an __init__.py inside the get_formats directory not outside, otherwise that directory will not be treated as a module.

However the easiest option is to use the sys module, like `sys.path.append` in the second answer here [Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder) , or like this: [How to import .py file from another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory)