# Import a submodule in a Python module

Tags: python, import

I have already read [Python: importing a sub‑package or sub‑module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12229580/python-importing-a-sub-package-or-sub-module) but this:

```
file                                content
============================================================================
main.py                             from mymodule.a import A; A()
mymodule/submodule/__init__.py      (empty)
mymodule/submodule/b.py             class B: pass
mymodule/__init__.py                (empty)
mymodule/a.py                       (see below)
```

`mymodule/a.py`:

```
import submodule
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = submodule.B()
```

fails with:

> File "a.py", line 1, in 
> import submodule
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'submodule'

when lauching the script `main.py`.

**Question: how should I import `submodule` in `mymodule/a.py`?**

Comment: Have you tried placing 'submodule.py' inside the 'a.py' directory? 
it would be helpful if you could post the file hierarchy of the project

Comment: @EsvinJoshua Not possible, submodule is not a .py file, it's a directory. See my question, the file hierarchy/tree structure is in the first column.

Comment: I assume that you have to write "from b import B" in your submodule/init.py and then from mymodule/a.py you should be able to make "from submodule import B"

Comment: well in that case you would have to ( as @ottonormal) suggested, get the directory then get the file;
from submodule import b.py

Comment: What is the canonical way to do this? This is a common scenario when writing modules with submodules.

Comment: check out this SO post:

[How to import .py file from another directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22955684/how-to-import-py-file-from-another-directory)

I think this is what you are looking for?

Comment: for my understanding is this the right way to do this. The answer from Gabriel d'Agosto could work too, but you will not being able to import specific classes or functions from that package. Only the whole one

Answer (score 2):

**TLDR:**

`mymodule/a.py`:

```py
from . import submodule
# or
import mymodule.submodule as submodule
```

Once you run your `main.py`, python adds to your `sys.path` the path to `main.py` folder. Python can now search subfolders to find modules trying to be imported. Once you import `a.py`, python DOES NOT add anything else to `sys.path`, therefore, to be able import subfolders, you need to do either relative importing (`from . import submodule`), which you can do because you aren't running `a.py` as your main file, OR do a full import, doing `import mymodule.submodule`, since python can search starting on `main.py` folder.